# Is there a way to display only certain columns in pandas without typing them manually?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv file with 15 columns. The headers are: `Time, Force, Stroke` and they go up to: `Time.15, Force.15 and Stroke.15`. Now, I would like to get a table with just Force columns (`Force, Force.1, Force.2, ...`).

I know I can do it manually `df[["Force", "Force.1,...]]`, but is there any "smarter", faster way to do it? 15 columns can be typed manually relatively fast, but sometimes I get a csv file with 50 columns (or more)...it would get very time consuming to do it by typing each header. Until now I did the work in excel or sigma plot (not a pro in either), but I thought I'd try to automate those tasks with python.

Comment: column's names are strings so you can generate list with these strings using `for` loop pr list comprehension (with `for` inside) - `["Force"] + ["Force." + str(x) for x in range(1,16)]`

Comment: You can also get all names and keep filter those which starts with "Force" - `startswith("Force")`

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can cleverly generate a list of strings ["Force", "Force.1", "Force.2"] with list comprehensions or loops, then use this for indexing.

**List Comprehension way**

```
cols= ["Force"] + ["Force.{}".format(x) for x in range(1,16)]
df[cols]
```

**loop way**

```
cols=["Force]
for i in range(1,16):
    cols.append("Force.{}".format(i))    
df[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Column's names are strings so you can generate list with these strings using `for` loop or list comprehension (with `for` loop inside)

```
names = ["Force"] + ["Force." + str(x) for x in range(1, 16)]
```

You can also get all names and filter those which starts with "Force"

```
names = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('Force')]
```

This way you don't have to even know how many columns have name `Force`

---

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Force': [1,2,3],
    'Force.1': [1,2,3],
    'Force.2': [1,2,3],
    'Other': [1,2,3],
    'Other.1': [1,2,3],
    'Other.2': [1,2,3],
})

print(df)

names = ['Force'] + ['Force.' + str(x) for x in range(1, 3)]
print(names)
print(df[names])

names = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('Force')]
print(names)
print(df[names])
```

---

**EDIT:** I found that `regex` can be used to select columns - ie. `'^Force'` for columns which name star with `Force`. This way you don't have to generate list with names

```
print( df.filter(regex='^Force') )
```

Doc: [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at pandas [read_csv documentaion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll find an argument called `usecols` which allows you to specify which columns to load e.g. `pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', usecols = [3 * x + 1 for x in range(16)])`